# Python Deap GP Evaluating individual causes error

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-programming, deap, evaluation-function

I am currently experiencing an issue whenever I try to evaluate an individual using the GP portion of DEAP.

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImageGP.py", line 297, in <module>
    pop, logs = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, 0.9, 0.1, 60, stats=mstats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/deap/algorithms.py", line 148, in eaSimple
    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
  File "ImageGP.py", line 229, in evalFunc
    func = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/deap/gp.py", line 451, in compile
    return eval(code, pset.context, {})
  File "<string>", line 1
    lambda oValue,oAvg13,oAvg17,oAvg21,sobelVal(v),sobelVal(h),edgeVal,blotchVal: [[[0, 75, 82.2857142857, 83.0, 82.9090909091, 4, 12, 4, 180], ... Proceed to print out all of my data ...  [0, 147, 151.244897959, 150.728395062, 150.73553719, 248, 244, 5, 210]]]
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anyone has any ideas about what could be causing this problem, then I would really appreciate some advice. My current evaluation function looks like this:

```
def evalFunc(individual, data, points):
    func = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)
    total = 1.0

    for point in points:
        tmp = [float(x) for x in data[point[1]][point[0]][1:9]]
        total += int((0 if (func(*tmp)) < 0 else 1) == points[2])

    print ("Fitness: " + str(total))
    return total,
```

Where the data contains the data being used (the values for the 8 variables listed in the error) and point specifying the x and y co-ordinates from which to get those 8 values. Thank you for your suggestions!